# Export a Power BI dataset

Tags: powershell, powerbi

In the Power BI service, I see I can right-click a dataset and choose "Download this file".  How can I use PowerShell to do this?

I have seen Microsoft's documentation on this.  I see Export-PowerBIDataFlow and Export-PowerBIReport, but there is no Export-PowerBIDataset.

Let's assume I don't have a report that uses the dataset in question, so Export-PowerBIReport will not work for me.

Passing the ID for a dataset to Export-PowerBIReport doesn't appear to work, even though a report and a dataset are the same thing from the perspective of interacting with them in Power BI Desktop.  And both (manually) export from the service as .pbix files.

```
Login-PowerBIServiceAccount -Environment USGov

$ws = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -Name "My Office Workspace"
$wsid = $ws.Id
foreach ($d in $ds) {
    if ($d.Name = $name) {
        $dsid = $d.Id
    }
}

$fldr = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Downloads"
$file = Join-Path $fldr $name

if (Test-Path "$file.pbix") {
    Remove-Item "$file.pbix"
}

Export-PowerBIReport -Id $dsid -OutFile "$file.pbix"
```

```
Export-PowerBIReport : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
```

I suspect the error is caused by `$dsid` being the ID of a dataset, not a report.

Side note, related to my efforts:  It appears that Get-PowerBIDataset is broken.  With many datasets in the workspace, these two lines of code do exactly the same thing (return all of the datasets), contrary to the documentation:

```
$ds = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $wsid
$ds = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $wsid -Name "My dataset"
```

Is that expected or a known problem?

**Update**
based on Sam Nseir's answer.

```
Login-PowerBIServiceAccount -Environment USGov

$dt       = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$wsname   = "My Office Workspace"
$dsname   = "My Dataset"
$rptname  = $dsname + $dt
$fldr     = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Downloads"
$fileout  = Join-Path $fldr "$dsname.pbix"
$fileseed = Join-Path $fldr "seed.pbix"
$seedname = "seed$dt"  # lazily trying to avoid naming conflicts
$copyname = "copy$dt"  # lazily trying to avoid naming conflicts

$ws = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -Name $wsname
$wsid = $ws.Id
$ds = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $wsid
foreach ($d in $ds) {
    if ($d.Name = $dsname) {
        $dsid = $d.Id
    }
}

$dsbefore = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $wsid
$r  = New-PowerBIReport -Path $fileseed -Name $seedname -WorkspaceId $wsid
$rid = $r.Id
#$r
$dsafter = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $wsid

foreach ($dsa in $dsafter) {
    $found = 0
    foreach ($dsb in $dsbefore) {
        if ($dsa.Id -eq $dsb.Id) {
            $found = 1
            break
        }
    }
    if ($found -eq 0) {
        #"New dataset found:  $($dsa.Name)"
        $dsnewid = $dsa.Id
        break
    }
}

$rc = Copy-PowerBIReport -Name $copyname -Id $rid -WorkspaceId $wsid -TargetWorkspaceId $wsid -TargetDatasetId $dsid
$rcid = $rc.Id
$rcid

if (Test-Path $fileout) {
    Remove-Item $fileout
}


Export-PowerBIReport -Id $rcid -OutFile $fileout

Remove-PowerBIReport -Id $rcid -WorkspaceId $wsid
Remove-PowerBIReport -Id $rid -WorkspaceId $wsid
#  There is no Remove-PowerBIDataset cmdlet, so let's try the Power BI REST API
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "groups/$wsid/datasets/$dsnewid" -Method Delete
```

So I have:
created a report
copied the report and wired it up to the desired dataset
exported the copied report (desired dataset)
deleted the copied report
deleted the new report
deleted the new dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power BI Service, report and dataset are separate with different IDs. Ultimately, you will need a report attached to your dataset, for you to then export the report (with the dataset).

Here is a solution for when you don't have a report for the dataset that you want to export.

1. Create a new PBIX locally, with no visuals, and just one simple table.
2. Publish this PBIX to "My Workspace" or any other workspace.
3. In PowerShell, get the **report** ID and Workspace ID of this new report you just published.
4. Use `Copy-PowerBIReport` to copy this report to your target workspace where the dataset is in, **and** use `-TargetDatasetId` to have the copied report be bound to the dataset.
5. Now do `Export-PowerBIReport` on the new copied report.
6. Optional - `Remove-PowerBIReport` to delete the copied report if you have no further need for it.

Comment: That got me thinking differently.  I can just use PowerShell to create a dummy report to wire up to the dataset.  Then I went to the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.reports/new-powerbireport?view=powerbi-ps.  Now I remember:  In order to create a report, I must first create a report.  "Error:  too much recursion"  Will Power BI ever be cloud-based and not require a desktop app?  Basically, what you're saying is that in order to manage Power BI content, I must do manual tasks in Power BI Desktop.  Lovely.

Comment: And if I do this I have no way to clean up after.  I think this means, use a local pbix file to create a report in My Workspace, *which also creates a dataset*.  Copy the report to the target workspace and make it reference the target dataset.  Export the resulting report.  Deleting the report copy from the target workspace.  Delete the report from My Workspace.  But I have no way to delete the newly-created dataset from My Workspace.  There is no Remove-PowerBIDataset commandlet.

Comment: Apparently the Power BI commandlets are incomplete.  Maybe I'll have better luck with the REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/

Comment: The process can't be to publish to My Workspace or any other workspace, then copy to the target workspace.  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-export-to-pbix#limitations-when-downloading-a-report-pbix-file:  "You can't download a copy of a report if the copy is saved in a workspace other than where the original report is saved."  Yes, this applies downloading the report through either the UI or the Export-PowerBIReport cmdlet.

Comment: I even tried copying it back to My Workspace after wiring up the dataset.

Comment: What is your overall scenario or use case?

Comment: I'll need to be able to open datasets in Power BI Desktop to assist users.  With potentially 1200 workspaces in my future, I'd rather not spend all day using the crappy UI.

Comment: So the answer above works and gets you to where you need to be - **apart** from now needing to delete the extra dataset. You tried `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod` and got an error - is that the full error message? I wonder if it is due to your workspace permissions - what permissions do you have?

Comment: That logic only works if you assume that generating a pile of poo is part of my requirement.  It is not.  Permissions:  Power BI Administrator

Comment: Hence the "**apart**" emphasis. When you try deleting the 'poo' dataset with `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod` any additional error message returned to give clues as to why it failed? Are you able to delete it via the UI in the portal?

Comment: Yes, I can delete from the UI.  I am the Power BI Admin.  Looking at the Power BI CLI project on github, it looks like deleting a dataset was possible at one point.  But the product was deprecated in 2017 and hasn't been updated since.  Since Power BI changes daily, it's likely something has changed.

Comment: Try `Resolve-PowerBIError -Last` directly after the `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod ...` to see if you get any more info on error.

Comment: Try a simple test like `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "groups" -Method Get` - if that also fails then I wonder if you need to specify the full Url since you're on USGov. So then try `https://api.powerbigov.us/v1.0/myorg/groups` and if that works, then use the full Url for the delete.

Comment: Most methods invoked by `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod` work fine.  Deleting a dataset is the only thing I have discovered to-date that just doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to share more detailed error message? "Try Resolve-PowerBIError -Last directly after the Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod ... to see if you get any more info on error"

Comment: Now I feel dumb.  I was using My Workspace at one point.  When I switched to using the target workspace, I forgot to add `-Workspaceid $wsid` to lines 22 and 26.  It's working now.  Oddly, `Resolve-PowerBIError` returns a bunch of errors even though the process works and there are no errors displayed without that command.  I'll update my "update" section in the question.  Thanks for the help.